# How to absolutely position an element after the first line of a title

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying place an HTML element next to the end of the first line of a heading.
For a better understanding, I took screenshots of what it looks like for now and what it should look like.

What it looks like:
[image: What it looks like]

What it should look like:
[image: What it should look like]

As you can see, I used the `::first-line` pseudo-selector to change the background of the first line of the title in red.

So far I have tried to add a `::after` to the `::first-line` but there are two issues. First, I did not manage to display a text content in the `::after`. Second, you can't add html content to both `::before` and `::after` so it was pointless.

You should know that the "sunshines" are not an image but an actual html element :

```
<div className={css.container}>
   <div className={css.shine1}></div>
   <div className={css.shine2}></div>
   <div className={css.shine3}></div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5px;

  div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: $mainColor;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
  }
  .shine1 {
    width: 26px;
    transform: rotate(-95deg) translate(20px, 5px);
  }
  .shine2 {
    width: 32px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(20px);
  }
  .shine3 {
    width: 26px;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(15px);
  }
}
```

This is JSX with scss modules. But basically the same syntax as HTML/CSS.

Do you have any idea on how to do it, I guess it is possible since the css is capable to know where the end of the line is since I can change the background.

Comment: Please add all relevant code here, we need the css as well as the html. Also you have some framework that you are building this on, that is not pure html?

Comment: it won't work with css alone. you gonna need some JavaScript. Is JS ok?

Comment: @MaZoli Sure, no problem with javascript

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.

Although my solution is very "hacky", it works fine in any test case I thought about.

My solution is to create a hidden replica of the first line on top of the title with the same css properties. Once that is done I just get the width of the replica and use that value to define the `left` property of my sunshines.

This is the function I use to get the first line of the text :

```js
const getFirstLine = el => {
  const text = el.innerHTML;

  //set the innerHTML to a character
  el.innerHTML = 'a';
  //get the offsetheight of the single character
  const singleLineHeight = el.offsetHeight;

  //split all innerHTML on spaces
  const arr = text.split(' ');

  //cur is the current value of the text we are testing to see if
  //it exceeds the singleLineHeight when set as innerHTML
  //prev is the previously tested string that did not exceed the singleLineHeight
  //cur and prev start as empty strings
  let cur = '';
  let prev = '';

  //loop through, up to array length
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //examine the rest of text that is not already in previous string
    const restOfText = text.substring(prev.length, text.length);

    //the next space that is not at index 0
    const nextIndex =
      restOfText.indexOf(' ') === 0
        ? restOfText.substring(1, restOfText.length).indexOf(' ') + 1
        : restOfText.indexOf(' ');

    //the next part of the rest of the text
    cur += restOfText.substring(0, nextIndex);

    //set the innerHTML to the current text
    el.innerHTML = cur;

    //now we can check its offsetHeight
    if (el.offsetHeight > singleLineHeight) {
      //once offsetHeight of cur exceeds singleLineHeight
      //previous is the first line of text
      //set innerHTML = prev so
      el.innerHTML = prev;
      //we can grab the innertext
      const firstLine = el.innerText;
      const indexOfSecondLine = prev.lastIndexOf('<');

      //reset el
      el.innerHTML = text;

      return firstLine;
    }

    //offsetheight did not exceed singleLineHeight
    //so set previous = cur and loop again
    //prev = cur + ' ';
    prev += cur.substring(prev.length, cur.length);
  }
  el.innerHTML = text;
  return text;
};
```

If you want to do the same be careful to wait for the fonts of the web page to be loaded or the width you will be getting will be wrong.

```js
document.fonts.ready.then(function () {})
```

I have also managed to handle when the title has the `text-align: center;` property by adding a `margin-left/right: auto;` to the replica that I then get and add to the calculated `left` using this :

```js
parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(invisibleTitle).marginLeft)
```

I know it is not perfect, but since there is no easy way to do that in css it is the only working way that I found.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it if it's possible to separate the two lines in heading,
html:

```
<header>
        <div>
            <div class="first-line">
                <p>
                    sample title, pretty long

                <div className={css.container}>
                    <div className={css.shine1}></div>
                    <div className={css.shine2}></div>
                    <div className={css.shine3}></div>
                </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <p>
                that is wrapping in two lines
            </p>
        </div>
    </header>
```

css :

```
header .first-line{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5px;

  
}
.container div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.shine1 {
  width: 26px;
  transform: rotate(-95deg) translate(20px, 5px);
}
.shine2 {
  width: 32px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(20px);
}
.shine3 {
  width: 26px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(15px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am using my titles as a component so I cannot hard code the two parts. Also I need to add internationalization to the texts of the website. There are two versions of each title